# android close app with background running

Tags: android

I have an app with a background process running with a notification image on top of it. I want to close the app by clicking a button inside of the App. Currently I have to force close it from the settings. What do I have to change in the code bellow to achieve this?

1:

```
 Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    homeIntent.addCategory( Intent.CATEGORY_HOME );
    homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(homeIntent);
```

2:`finish();`

3:`System.exit(0);`

The three codes above closes the app but the background process with the notication image is still running.

Comment: @Kartheek while editing you must also check the spelling

Comment: Dont understand the question. Do u want the service running but the icon disapear?

Comment: i want whole app to be stopped like force stop

Comment: have u tried System.exit(0); ?

Comment: yeah written in question see

Comment: Dont do  [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon?lq=1)

Answer (score -1):

For remove top notification

```
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

For stop service :

```
stopService(new Intent(this,ServiceName.class));
```

In service class :

```
stopSelf();
```